# C# Fluent Assertions global options for ShouldBeEquivalentTo

Tags: c#, fluent-assertions

In Fluent Assertions when comparing objects with DateTime properties there are sometimes a slight mismatch in the milliseconds and the comparison fail. The way we get around it is to set the comparison option like so:

```
actual.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(expected,
        options =>
            options.Using<DateTime>(ctx => ctx.Subject.Should().BeCloseTo(ctx.Expectation))
                .WhenTypeIs<DateTime>());
```

Is there a way to set this up once and have it always apply instead of having to specify it every time we call ShouldBeEquivalentTo?

Update1:
Tried the following approach but it doesn't seem to work, test fails on 1 millisecond difference. The new default does not seem to get called by the factory.

```
using System;
using FluentAssertions;
using FluentAssertions.Equivalency;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    class Test
    {
        public DateTime TestDateTime { get; set; }
    }

    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void SettingFluentAssertionDefault()
        {
            // arrange
            var defaultAssertionOptions = EquivalencyAssertionOptions<DateTime>.Default;

            EquivalencyAssertionOptions<DateTime>.Default = () =>
            {
                var config = defaultAssertionOptions();
                config.Using<DateTime>(ctx => ctx.Subject.Should().BeCloseTo(ctx.Expectation)).WhenTypeIs<DateTime>();
                return config;
            };

            var testDateTime = DateTime.Now;
            var expected = new Test {TestDateTime = testDateTime};

            // act
            var actual = new Test {TestDateTime = testDateTime.AddMilliseconds(1)};

            // assert
            actual.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(expected);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the TestInitialize itself called?

Comment: Yes, TestInitialize is called. I even added the code snippet directly to the test before I perform the check and it doesn't seem to get hit. Updating the question with a complete test unit.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Actually, you can. The default configuration factory is exposed by the `static` property `EquivalencyAssertionOptions<Test>.Default`. You can easily assign an alternative configuration for a particular data type, or extend the default configuration with additional behavior. Something like:

```
var defaultAssertionOptions = EquivalencyAssertionOptions<Test>.Default;

EquivalencyAssertionOptions<Test>.Default = () =>
{
    var config = defaultAssertionOptions();
    config.Using<DateTime>(ctx => ctx.Subject.Should().BeCloseTo(ctx.Expectation)).WhenTypeIs<DateTime>();
    return config;
};
```

If you want you can get the current default and tuck that away in some variable that you use from your factory method.

Comment: Maybe I am doing it wrong but I tried adding the following to my test initialize but it doesn't seem to get called when the factory is instantiated.


    EquivalencyAssertionOptions<DateTime>.Default = () =>
 {
  var config = defaultAssertionOptions();
  config.Using<DateTime>(ctx => ctx.Subject.Should().BeCloseTo(ctx.Expectation)).WhenTypeIs<DateTime>();
  return config;
 };

Comment: Also, the proposed code doesn't compile because the constructor for EquivalencyAssertionOptions is private.

Comment: Actually, my example was wrong. Since you're executing an assertion on an instance of `Test` class, you must override the default options for that specific class and not the `DateTime` that is used internally. I've just tested this using your example and updated my original answer.

Answer (score 26):

Now this can be done with the AssertionOptions static class. To use a simple example:

```
[TestInitialize]
public void TestInit() {
  AssertionOptions.AssertEquivalencyUsing(options => options.ExcludingMissingMembers());
}
```

Or as in the example above:

```
AssertionOptions.AssertEquivalencyUsing(options =>
  options.Using<DateTime>(ctx => ctx.Subject.Should().BeCloseTo(ctx.Expectation)).WhenTypeIs<DateTime>()
);
```

Comment: Just in case anyone is as stupid as me - bear in mind that being static, these options persist throughout the entire test run (which was of course the O.P.'s request). I had a test which set the options to ignore equivalency comparison on properties with a certain name, assuming that this was being reassigned in each test. It wasn't, it was adding a new rule every time, so each test used the previous test's 'ignore list' as well as its own. Lesson learnt....

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid the closest thing you can come to, is providing new methods

```
public static void ShouldBeEquivalentToDef<T>(this T subject, object expectation, string reason = "",
    params object[] reasonArgs)
{
    ShouldBeEquivalentToDef(subject, expectation, config => config, reason, reasonArgs);
}

public static void ShouldBeEquivalentToDef<T>(this T subject, object expectation,
    Func<EquivalencyAssertionOptions<T>, EquivalencyAssertionOptions<T>> config, string reason = "", params object[] reasonArgs)
{
    var context = new EquivalencyValidationContext
    {
        Subject = subject,
        Expectation = expectation,
        CompileTimeType = typeof (T),
        Reason = reason,
        ReasonArgs = reasonArgs
    };

    var defConstructedOptions = config(EquivalencyAssertionOptions<T>.Default());
    defConstructedOptions.Using<DateTime>(ctx => ctx.Subject.Should().BeCloseTo(ctx.Expectation))
            .WhenTypeIs<DateTime>()

    new EquivalencyValidator(defConstructedOptions).AssertEquality(context);
}
```