# Opposite of ShouldBeEquivalentTo

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fluent-assertions

I am writing unit tests in c#.  `ShouldBeEquivalentTo` makes sense for positive cases, but for negative cases what do you use>  I have not found anything like `ShouldNotBeEquivalentTo`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20693872/c-sharp-fluent-assertions-global-options-for-shouldbeequivalentto

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't exist. The best you can do is to wrap the call to `ShouldBeEquivalentTo` and catch the `AssertFailedException`. You could create an extension method for that.